# How can I get a list of 25 numbers from user with formatting ..."please enter a[1]=","please enter a[2]=",

Tags: list-manipulation, input

Do[Input["please enter a[",i,"]"],{i,1,25}];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might  be

```
data =Last@Reap[Do[Sow@Input[Row[{"please enter a[", i, "]"}]], {i, 3}]]
```

[image]